# cURL - Multiple Requests and echo content

Tags: php, curl, return

I dont know if I cannot understand or I dont want to understand but I looked for a solution and didnt found one that could help me.

For example: I do a request with cURL and echo the content. This works fine for me.
Now the site opens but my browser does 5 more requests. The 5 requests all need a referer and the .php is shown as the referer. The referer is the url in the address bar. So because I cannot fake the url because of phishing sites and so on, I have to do the other 5 requests.

But everything Ive tried doesnt work. Everytime my browser does this 5 requests after echo the content I received with the first request. How can I do all 6 requests (the first one I do and the other 5) and return the site after the this so my browser will not do any requests?

Comment: I can't understand what is being asked here. Please clarify.

Comment: I do a get request and with php I return what I get. So when I do a get request for google.com and return with echo ($response); The page will be loaded but my browser does more requests like       GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1 
I want to do this request with cURL aswell so that my browser dont have to do this request.

Comment: To say it in one sentence, I have to send a request to the resulting page I get with the first request so the browser dont have to send the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you only need to spoof the referrer, you actually CAN do that with curl:

```
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
```